# Multiple Divs / Classes On an Opaque Background

Tags: css, html, opacity

My goal (and the question of how-to) is to have an opaque / white background with black fields over the opaque area to serve as content holders. Here is what I have now:

```
/* translucent background*/
.background 
{
    width:950px;
    height:1024px;
    margin: 9px auto 10px;

    background-color:#ffffff;
    opacity:0.35;
    filter:alpha(opacity=35); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    z-index:0;
}

/*content wrapper*/
.content 
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;

    width:950px;
    height:1024px;
    margin: 9px auto 10px;

    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    z-index:1;
}

/*one of three content fields*/
.anounce_bar
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;

    width:940px;
    height:225px;
    float: left;

    border: 5px 5px 5px 5px;

    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    z-index:2;
}

<div class="background"></div>
<div class="content">
    <!--Top announcement bar-->  
    <div class="anounce_bar">
    </div>

    <!--Left side nav bar-->
<div class="nav" style="height: 1024px; ">
    </div>

    <!--Right side content window-->
    <div class="content_window">

    </div>
</div>
```

Right now its showing the anounce_bar below the translucent background.. how do I get the bar (and subsequent nav & content_window) to go on top of .background?

Note: I have other content, including a top 'masthead' image and a background JPG that might be screwing with this.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

**Update:**

This was an issue with opacity inheritance - the work around I used is described very well [here](http://stevenyork.com/tutorial/pure_css_opacity_and_how_to_have_opaque_children)

'background' class became #background without any opacity, and a new item was added:#background .transparency with absolute positioning and opacity.

```
<div id="background">
    <div class='transparency'></div>
    /*OTHER STUFF*/
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order

```
<div class="anounce_bar"></div>
<div class="background"></div>
```

That should work.

Comment: 'anounce_bar' is inside the 'content' div. Placing the 'background' div after the 'content' div just seems to flip the two, without placing one on top of the other.

Comment: Use the answer Priya gave you but add this to background: 'position:absolute;' close the div: '<div class="background"></div>' and remove background color from content.

http://jsfiddle.net/BN6Ce/4/

Comment: That looks like it worked, but I'd like for my content to be relative - there is a background and a 'masthead' image that it needs to stay with. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Post the code in jsfiddle of your images and content, i'll help you (+1)

Comment: I got it to work by doing the workaround described here: http://stevenyork.com/tutorial/pure_css_opacity_and_how_to_have_opaque_children, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="content">
    <!--Top announcement bar-->  
      <div class="anounce_bar" style="color: white">Anounce Bar</div>

    <!--Left side nav bar-->
      <div class="nav" style="height: 24px; width: 940px; background-color: green; float:left;">Nav</div>

    <!--Right side content window-->
    <div class="content_window" style="height: 24px; width: 940px; background-color: yellow; float:left;">Content Window</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/BN6Ce/2/)

Comment: That solved the issue of placing one on top of the other, but now the anounce_bar is opaque as well..

Comment: @Maxxra -- Update the link..let me know if this solves yous issue http://jsfiddle.net/BN6Ce/3/

Comment: 'anounce_bar' is still showing translucent instead of solid black.